# Create WSDL WebService Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, wsdl

I want to create WebService based on WSDL in Ruby on Rails 3.

I found [a tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ws-rubyrails/), but it is only for Rails 2.

Anyone knows good tutorial for doing it in Rails 3? Or maybe someone knows how to make this tutorial work with Rails 3?

Comment: Asking for tutorials is close enough to a [tag:books] question, which is generally regarded as **not constructive** and may be closed. Likewise, asking how to port a large, archaic Rails 2 tutorial to Rails 3 is overly broad and may be flagged as **not a real question**. See this [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/closed-questions).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [wash_out](https://github.com/inossidabile/wash_out) gem. It might be helpful.